# Regular expression to match a string when reading a file

Tags: python, regex

I have files which contain information in the following manner

**2458813.92557** 10 20 30 **@00FA0040000000010100005AB9000FFE86000F3596109000000703000100001000000000000036404E000000004000000020000000000032***

All of this is in the same line. I am only interested in getting only the portions in bold. I have the following regular expression to get what i want:

```
^(\d{7}\.\d{5}).*@([\dA-Z]+)\*
```

The regex works fine but when i use it this in python it does not include the @ and the * in the second bold string. I am using `re.match(r'^(\d{7}\.\d{5}).*@([\dA-Z]+\*)')` in python. I would love to know why this is and what would be the solution to it.

Thanks

Comment: Include these chars into the group - `^(\d{7}\.\d{5}).*(@[\dA-Z]+\*)`

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're forcing yourself to use regex when you have all the power of Python? This would be incredibly simple to solve with some basic string splitting.

Comment: The regex from Wiktor Stribizew helped. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Grouping was wrong, use below regex.

```
^(\d{7}\.\d{5}).*(@[\dA-Z]+\*)
```